# Why is it so hard to make 64-bit versions of software?

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

What are all the aspects must be taken into account when designing your software into 64-bit environment, and why wouldn't the same code work as 32-bit and 64-bit (when talking about applications)?

Drivers obviously are a different beast, missing 64-bit drivers are infamous problem for almost all hardware. What's so different in that domain that it's next to impossible to find drivers?

**Why is it so hard to make 64-bit versions of software?**

Edit: Let's forget the basic flaws of old, buggy software with magic numbers, etc. and think you'd create the software yourself, to be compatible with both. What aspects do you need to take into account, and are there things you just can't overcome with current compiler design? All the missing 64-bit software can not simply be because people like code with magic numbers?! :)

**Conclusion**: It seems to be all about human laziness and historical reasons, instead of technical reasons.

Comment: You should be more specific if you want a good answer. For example, it is brainless to make 64 bit versions of .NET applications - set it to compile as Any CPU or x64. So obviously, you are not talking about .NET applications, but what *are* you talking about? :)

Comment: I'm asking in general what is the technical reason which apparently makes it impossible to use exact same codebase to build 32-bit and 64-bit apps. Since if it would be just about recompiling, all libraries would also be available as 64-bit etc, then all apps could too be just recompiled to 64-bit -> ie. no problem.

Comment: "All the missing 64-bit software can not simply be because people like code with magic numbers?!" - a lot of missing 64 bit software might be because it is not needed. Someone please correct me if I am wrong, but the rule of thumb I have heard is: unless you are potentially addressing more than 4 GB of memory, you should compile as 32 bit.

Comment: @Nate - At least on Windows, 32-bit programs run on an emulation layer (WOW64). Also, 32-bit programs on Windows don't see Windows the same way 64-bit programs do, because of things like registry/file redirection and other things for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @In silice: WOW64 is not (always) an emulation layer. On the most common AMD64 architecture the CPU is simply switched into 32-bit mode for 32-bit threads and no emulation is needed. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64

Comment: @Nate Pinchot: 4GB limit is not really relevant here. I'm just trired of SW that doesn't work on 64-bit (despite WOW64) and when speaking of drivers memory isn't issue anyways. But I guess it all comes to human lazyness after all :(

Comment: Well of course--even if it does take an hour or less to make an application 64-bit ready, if nothing is gained from it, what's the point? That's an hour that you could have used to add a new feature to your product. There is also still the issue of dependencies not being available in 64-bit, which is actually more common than you think.

Comment: @musicfreak: I guess you have no idea how many systems are 64-bit now. If it was a one hour job, all software would be done 64-bit as well. The dependencies part is true as stated here already, thats what I'm referring as "historical reasons".

Comment: @Tuminoid: Not necessarily, due to the same laziness that you cited. :) For most applications, there is absolutely nothing to gain from writing a 64-bit version. 64-bit versions of Windows run 32-bit applications as well--same with Mac OS X as far as I'm aware. Linux is a different story, in which case you're right, but for Windows/Mac there's just no point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One specific reason why this might be hard is that pointer sizes are going to be different. Instead of a pointer taking up 32 bits, a pointer would now take up 64 bits.

That's a problem if the software somewhere shoehorns a pointer into an `int` via a `reinterpret_cast` in C++ (which may occur in some really low level code), and it happened to work because the size of an `int` and a pointer were the same size. Basically, the code assumed a certain size for a pointer.

Another way that can bite back is if the code is littered with magic numbers like `4` instead of `sizeof(void*)`, or `0xffffffff` instead of `INT_MAX` or something similar.

There might not be a 64-bit version of a software if it depends on a library or a function that is not available in 64 bits. You can't have an application that is part 32 bits and 64 bits. For example, in Windows, there's a function called [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591(VS.85).aspx) that can only accept 32-bits of data, so it's not very useful for 64-bit programs if a pointer needs to be passed to the function. That's why there's a function called [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898(v=VS.85).aspx) that can handle up to 64-bits in 64-bit programs and 32-bits in 32-bit programs.

Note that Internet Explorer runs on 32-bits by default even on 64-bit windows, because a huge majority of plugins for it are available only in 32-bits. A big example of this is [the Adobe Flash Player](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html), which is available only in 32-bits. So, apparently even for a big company like Adobe, porting for 64-bits may not always be trivial.

Bitshifting operations may be affected. For example, bit shifting `0x80000` left 10 times in 32 bits gives you `0x0`, but bit shifting `0x80000` left 10 times in 64 bits gives you `0x200000000`.

All that being said, there's no real technical reason why it's too difficult to port an application to 64-bits **if the code was written well.** The best case scenario is that a simple project reconfiguration and complete rebuild is all that's needed.

The cynical side of me say that companies use this as a way to implement planned obsolescence - force or encourage people to upgrade to/purchase the newest products!

Comment: But why is that a problem? Shouldn't compiler know better?

Comment: It does, but if the code uses `reinterpret_cast`, the compiler won't emit a diagnostic (which is why typecasting needs to be done carefully).

Comment: And I'm talking about reasonable quality software not filled with magic numbers etc. If it helps, think about creating software yourself to be compatible on both worlds.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but that library issue would be a non-issue if it was all about just recompiling. All libs would also then exist as 32- and 64-bit versions. I'm searching for an answer why that isn't the case :)

Comment: @Tuminoid - that depends on the library authors actually taking the time to do that. :-) The library source code may not even be available anymore.

Comment: Even a perfectly portable program could be subject to stack overflows because the x64 calling convention can make a 64-bit program take more than twice as much stack space as the same 32-bit program.

Answer (score 5):

The nutshell version: In the most popular family of languages — C and its children — the size and structure of data types is both very important and *implementation-defined*. In fact, C has a lot of implementation-dependent features. This means it's easy to write nonportable code. It's not impossible to write code that doesn't make assumptions about the underlying architecture, but it is really easy to depend on x86-specific behaviors without realizing what you've done until you try running the code in a different environment.

It's mainly these low-level features that make architecture independence hard. In higher-level languages like Python and C#, it's much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Reasonably written software is usually very easy to port to another architecture. Just look at NetBSD, Debian or other big free OSes... lots of open-source software works on more than two architectures.

The problem is that lots and lots of software is written with disregard to good practices. Making "it" work is usually the only thing typical programmer thinks of, disregarding further problems. Typical explanation is: why bother with good practices if customer doesn't see the code, and it works? Why spend more time on something that already works?

Drivers are slightly different here. Different architectures might handle low-level stuff in different ways. `x86` and `amd64` on Windows have another problem: Microsoft set more strict standards for `amd64` drivers--hardware companies do not bother to produce drivers for old hardware that complies with stricter requirements (again: why bother? customer usually already buys new hardware with their new 64-bit boxes; and if he doesn't, we will make him do that anyway by not providing drivers). Again, open source drivers very often work on both `amd64` and `x86`.

I've got a sound card which works quite well on both `x86` and `amd64` systems on Linux, but doesn't work with `amd64` Windows exactly because of this issue. So it was not impossible to write a driver for `amd64` for it; the hardware company just didn't want to.

So, the ultimate answer to your question is: money.

Comment: I've got a 6month old Canon color laser printer and they didn't provide 64-bit drivers, major pain in the ***. So buying new hardware doesn't provide happiness...